# How can I fix android gradle build making strange error

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I made a file manager app and now I am trying to build it to an APK. The problem is that every time I try to build it returns this error:

> error: failed processing manifest.

here's my manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="FileManager"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FileManager"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".FileListActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried everything, I found similar questions in the internet but none of them works for me, can someone please help.

Comment: Please add name attribute in the application tag where you have to write the class name which will extends Application class. Myclass extends Application { }.. and put this Myclass in the name attribute.

Comment: Share your error log so it can be understood better.